# Access the DOM of a PDF using WebDriver and FireFox's built-in PDF viewer

Tags: webdriver, javascript

I'm trying to use FireFox's built-in javascript PDF viewer with WebDriver so I can access the DOM of a PDF. However, FireFox has an Adobe plugin which takes over and displays the PDF. Whatever preferences I set in `about:config` don't help. I've tried various preferences, like:

```
    profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf,application/zip");
profile.SetPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types","application/pdf");
profile.SetPreference("extensions.autoDisableScopes", 0);
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", false);
profile.SetPreference("pdfjs.firstRun", false);
```

But whatever combination I use either kills the Adobe plugin *and* pdfjs or gives me a popup asking where to save the PDF. If I manually disable the Adobe plugin, the javascript viewer takes over

How can I disable the Adobe plugin, but keep FireFox's javascript PDF enabled and access the DOM of the PDF?

Comment: Is it an option to uninstall the adobe plugin?

Comment: Frustratingly, no.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (think setting `'pdfjs.migrationVersion'` did the trick)

```
FirefoxProfile desiredCapabilities = new FirefoxProfile();      
desiredCapabilities.setPreference(
"browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    "application/x-zip-compressed,application/zip,text/csv,text/CSV,application/octet-stream,application/pdf"); 
desiredCapabilities.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf");
desiredCapabilities.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2); 
desiredCapabilities.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", false); 
desiredCapabilities.setPreference("pdfjs.firstRun", false); 
desiredCapabilities.setPreference("pdfjs.migrationVersion", 1);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```